# CSS - Frontpage vs. Product Page

Tags: products, css, html

We're updating our website. We need the home page to basically have no background and we're loading images on them. You can see how this works in the images.

**Current Home Page:**

- Has white background
- Products page has white background

**New Home Page:**

- Has no background
- Products Page needs white background

I know it's a css thing, but can't seem to figure out what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* css rules for homepage */
body.cms-index-index {

}

/* css rules for category page */ 
body.catalog-category-view {

}

/* css rules for product page */
body.catalog-product-view {

}
```

Comment: Where would I add this? Bottom of css?

Comment: You can add it anywhere in css file.

Comment: @NKJWebteam : If the answer helped you to resolve your issue, then feel free to accept this answer. You can accept this answer by ticking the mark that you can see in the left section of this answer. Thanks

Comment: Did I mention that I love this place!